# Ruby - reading CSV from STDIN

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to read from .CSV file and create objects with attributes of every row.
My code works fine:

```
def self.load_csv
    puts "Name of a file?"
    filename = STDIN.gets.chomp
    rows = []
    text = File.read(filename).gsub(/\\"/,'""')
    CSV.parse(text, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      row = row.to_h
      row = row.each_with_object({}){|(k,v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v}
      rows << row
    end

    rows.map do |row|
      Call.new(row)
    end
  end
end
```

Now I wanted to take filename from STDIN. I simply changed:

```
def self.load_csv(filename)
    rows = []
    text = File.read(filename).gsub(/\\"/,'""')
    CSV.parse(text, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      row = row.to_h
      row = row.each_with_object({}){|(k,v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v}
      rows << row
    end

    rows.map do |row|
      Call.new(row)
    end
  end
end
```

and when I try ruby program.rb filename.csv I got error no implicit conversion of String into IO, and after removing line with `File.read` it does nothing - like an infinite loop maybe? Of course I invoke ceratain methods with STDIN argument in different parts of the code. I used similiar code for reading from STDIN with success in the past, what am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: Do you get the filename from STDIN and then pass it to the `load_csv` method as parameter?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I invoke load_csv(STDIN)

Comment: I changed it as you said, but know it does nothing - like an infinite loop

Comment: By the way, you can use: `ARGF.read`  that will work with piping to STDIN and with passing in a filename as a parameter. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-argf

Comment: no matter what I use it still throws error File.read(filename) - "no implicit conversion of String to IO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working:

```
require 'csv'

class Call
  def initialize(args)
  end
end

def load_csv(filename)
  rows = []
  text = File.read(filename).gsub(/\\"/,'""')
  CSV.parse(text, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
    row = row.to_h
    row = row.each_with_object({}){ |(k,v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v }
    rows << row
  end

  rows.map { |row| Call.new(row) }
end

filename = ARGV[0]
load_csv(filename)
```

Comment: I copied whole class from your answer and made it all identical - but after running it, it still does nothing. I can leave computer for hours and still nothing. Can it be any other reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you enter the name of the CSV file? The `gets` method is waiting indefinitely until you enter any string followed by enter.

Comment: I think I didn't put it in right words - I want to be able to run: ruby program.rb filename.csv

Comment: I edited the code, so it would work the way you want. You have to use `ARGV` to pass value from command line instead of `STDIN.gets`.

Comment: I would use ARGF, like this you can read from file(s) or stdin without any changes.